# Why do my settings keep getting reset and how can I get them to stop?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am having trouble with the new biker DLC for GTA 5 Online on Xbox One. I started an mc, but it won't keep me as the president and it won't keep my friends in, either. Every time I log on, I have to go back to the mc to set myself as the president again and add all my friends. Is there a fix for this? I even changed the option from session to lifetime, but it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know theres no fix, you have to invite your friends every time you log into a session. The same problem occured in the previous DLC, where you could build your own criminal organization. After all the ranks of your friends are saved so you dont have to promote your friends every time, at least thats the case in the PC-Version.